# Getting Data from a json sub array that has a subarray

Tags: php, json

I would like to retrieve the *LONG* data from a *JSON* code in a table which looks like

```
{"def":{"short":"the first, in place, time, order or rank (specifically, a firstfruit)","long":["first, beginning, best, chief",["beginning","first","chief","choice part"]]},"deriv":"from the same as H7218","pronun":{"ipa":"reʔˈʃɪi̯t̪","ipa_mod":"ʁeʔˈʃiːt","sbl":"rēʾšît","dic":"ray-SHEET","dic_mod":"ray-SHEET"}}

{"def":{"short":"the sky (as aloft; the dual perhaps alluding to the visible arch in which the clouds move, as well as to the higher ether where the celestial bodies revolve)","long":["heaven, heavens, sky",["visible heavens, sky",["as abode of the stars","as the visible universe, the sky, atmosphere, etc"],"Heaven (as the abode of God)"]]},"deriv":"dual of an unused singular שָׁמֶה; from an unused root meaning to be lofty","pronun":{"ipa":"ʃɔː.mɑˈjɪm","ipa_mod":"ʃɑː.mɑˈjim","sbl":"šāmayim","dic":"shaw-ma-YIM","dic_mod":"sha-ma-YEEM"}}
```

and more data, I did this :

```
$data_result = json_decode($data, true);

$long_definition_1 = $data_result['def']['long'][0];

$compter_long =  count($data_result['def']['long'][1]);


for($i=0; $i<$compter_long; $i++)
{

   $long_definition_1 .= ', ';  
   $long_definition_1 .= $data_result['def']['long'][1][$i];

}

echo $long_definition_1;
```

It works for the first line  and displayed :

```
Long Def 1 : first, beginning, best, chief, beginning, first, chief, choice part
```

but for the second line and other line it sends me this error

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in E:\A - A - SITES ET SERVER\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC9\data\localweb\BIBLES SQL BIBLEFORGE\BibleForgeDB-master\BibleForgeDB-master\brouillons.php on line 164
```

I've searched everywhere for days without solution. I will greatly appreciate your help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in your second one you also have an array in

```
['def']['long'][1][1]
```

Therefor it cannot put the array in the string

[image]

This is a very helpful website so easy see what is in your json http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: Thanks a lot but still i am not getting it clear. What exactly can i do to display every part of it because even when i visit  http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/  i still can not figure out what to do to display every part of my json in a variable.
And thanks again for the quick answer